# Как вывести несколько ответов retrofit2 в recyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, retrofit2

Есть RecyclerView привязанный к одному активити. Использую Retrofit2 и удачно парсю ответ в recyclerView.
Но проблема в том что я не знаю как передать туда ответ с еще нескольких ответов retrofit, т.к. апи написано так что в одном месте должно отображаться 4 ответа из retrofit'a. Т.е. одинаковый у них только параметр num. Мне нужно сравнить этот num с первым ответом потом со вторым и третьим. И вывести в recycler результат всех ответов.

public class Adapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter1.Adapter1VH>{

```
private List<1Response> 1ResponseList;
private Context context;

public Adapter1() {
}

public void setData(List<1Response> 1ResponseList) {
    this.1ResponseList = 1ResponseList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdapterPn4PayVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new Adapter1.Adapter1VH(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter1VH holder, int position) {
    1Response 1response = 1ResponseList.get(position);

    String num = 1response.getNum();
    String ray = 1response.getRay();
    String str = 1response.getStr();
    String hos = 1response.getHos();
    String kor = 1response.getKor();

    holder.num.setText(num);
    holder.ray.setText(ray);
    holder.str.setText(str);
    holder.hos.setText(hos);
    holder.kor.setText(kor);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 1ResponseList.size();
}

public class Adapter1VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView num;
    TextView ray;
    TextView str;
    TextView hos;
    TextView kor;

    public Adapter1VH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        num= itemView.findViewById(R.id.num);
        ray= itemView.findViewById(R.id.ray);
        str= itemView.findViewById(R.id.str);
        hos= itemView.findViewById(R.id.hos);
        kor= itemView.findViewById(R.id.kor);

        
    }
```

Activity:

```
public void first_retrofit(){
    1Request 1request = new 1Request();
    1request.setNum(this.num.getText().toString());

    Call<List<1Response>> 1ResponseCall = ApiClient.getUserService().first(1request, token);
    1ResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<1Response>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<List<1Response>> call, @NotNull Response<List<1Response>> response) {
            if(response.code()==200){
                List<1Response> 1responses = response.body();
                assert 1Responses != null;
                for(1Response 1response : 1Responses){

                    adapter1.setData(1Responses);
                    list_rv.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

В остальных трех запросах реализовано все так же. Буду рада любой помощи, заранее благодарю.

Comment: Во-первых, этот код не скомпилируется, у вас идентификаторы начинаются с цифр. Во-вторых, уточните в каком виде вы получаете несколько ответов: т.е. объекты имеют ту же структуру (т.е. тот же List<1Response>)? или там другие свойства, а соответственно ответ приходит в какой-то List<2Response>? Что и как вы собираетесь сравнивать и какой результат ожидаете? На самом деле в адаптер вы должны передать уже готовый список со всеми необходимыми для отображения данными, а все сравнения должны происходить в обработке ответов.

Comment: Да, другие ответы приходят в List<2Response>, List<3Response>. Т.е. в 1Response приходит массив из - num. Я этот массив отправляю запросом в 2Request и получаю ray, str. А так же этот num отправляю запросом в 3Request и получаю hos и kor. Т.е. это три разных Response и нужно отобразить еще и четвертый. А у меня пока получается только отобразить 1Respons

Answer (score 0):

При получении ответа модифицируйте объекты. Псевдокод:

```
// Поле в Activity
Map<String, Response1> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

onResponse(Response<List<Response1>> response)){
  for(r: response.body()){
     if(!result.containsKey(r.getNum()){
        result.put(r.getNum(), new Response1(r.getNum());
     }
     // для других ответов заполняем остальные поля
     result.get(r.getNum()).setRay(r.getRay());
     ...
  }
  adapter.setData(new ArrayList<>(result.values()));
}

Adapter1.setData(List<Response1> newData){
   this.responseList1 = newData;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Убрал DiffUtil, объекты мутабельны, diff не сработает, будет сравнивать объекты сами с собой, изменений не будет. Для DiffUtil можно клонировать объекты, но это из постоптимизаций.